# HTML 5 Video stretch

Tags: video, html

Can you make a video "stretch" to the width & height of the video element? Apparentlyby default, video gets scaled & fitted inside the video element, proportionally.

thanks

Answer (score 147, accepted):

I have tested by using object-fit: fill in CSS

Works good.

```
video {
  object-fit: fill;
}
```

From MDN (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/object-fit):

The object-fit CSS property specifies how the contents of a replaced element should be fitted to the box established by its used height and width.

Value: fill

The replaced content is sized to fill the element’s content box: the object’s concrete object size is the element’s used width and height.

Comment: Excellent! Thank you very much

Comment: the object-fit doesn't work on ie and edge, so if you want an inclusive solution you should replace it with a hack like 'transform:scaleX(2)'. they both work on the same principle: stretching the video. we should mention that the second solution, being a hack, has its own evil symptom: the video overflows horizontally, resulting in a horizontal scrollbar at the bottom of the page. but we can counter this problem quite easily with 'overflow-x:hidden' placed on the body tag.

Comment: Simple and Smart solution

Comment: Make sure that the video and the container have full width and height. `height: 100%; width: 100%`

Answer (score 38):

From [the spec for `<video>`](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/video.html):

> Video content should be rendered inside the element's playback area such that the video content is shown centered in the playback area at the largest possible size that fits completely within it, with the video content's aspect ratio being preserved. Thus, if the aspect ratio of the playback area does not match the aspect ratio of the video, the video will be shown letterboxed or pillarboxed. Areas of the element's playback area that do not contain the video represent nothing.

There are no provisions for stretching the video instead of letterboxing it. This is likely because stretching gives a very bad user experience, and most of the time is not what is intended. Images are stretched to fit by default, and because of that, you see lots of images which are badly distorted online, most likely due to a simple mistake in specifying the height and width.

You can achieve a stretched effect using [CSS 3 transforms](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-2d-transforms/), though those aren't fully standardized or implemented in all browsers yet, and the ones in which it is implemented, you need to use a vendor prefix such as `-webkit-` or `-moz-`. Here's an example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<style>
video { 
  -webkit-transform: scaleX(2); 
  -moz-transform: scaleX(2);
}
</style>
<video src="http://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/big_buck_bunny.ogv"></video>
```

Comment: Great answer. Just to add here for IE, use  `-ms-transform: scaleX(2);`

Answer (score 11):

This worked perfectly for me

http://coding.vdhdesign.co.nz/?p=29

```
$VideoElement = $(_VideoElement); //Cache Jquery reference of this
var iOriginalVideoHeight =  _VideoElement.videoHeight;
var iCurrentVideoHeight = $VideoElement.height();
var iVideoContainerHeight = $VideoElement.parent().height();
var iCurrentScale = iOriginalVideoHeight/iCurrentVideoHeight;
var iScaleY = (iVideoContainerHeight / iOriginalVideoHeight)*iCurrentScale;


//Important to note: Set the origin to the top left corner (0% 0%), or else the position of the video goes astray
 $VideoElement.css({
    "transform-origin": "0% 0%",
    "transform":"scaleY(" + iScaleY +")",
    "-ms-transform-origin" : "0% 0% ", /* IE 9 */
    "-ms-transform":"scaleY(" + iScaleY +")", /* IE 9 */
    "-moz-transform-origin" : "0% 0%", /* Firefox */
    "-moz-transform":"scaleY(" + iScaleY +")", /* Firefox */
    "-webkit-transform-origin": "0% 0%", /* Safari and Chrome */
    "-webkit-transform":"scaleY(" + iScaleY +")", /* Safari and Chrome */
    "-o-transform-origin":"0% 0%", /* Opera */
    "-o-transform":"scaleY(" + iScaleY +")" /* Opera */
 });
```

Comment: You are the only person who made this working like it should be, all the others were giving examples but it was not doing the job. Thank you for sharing.

Answer (score 8):

There is also [the object-fit CSS property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/object-fit), which will likely give you what you need.

Incidentally, I think this request is realated to [How can I make HTML 5 video playback fit to frame instead of maintaining aspect ratio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2371040/how-can-i-make-html-5-video-playback-fit-to-frame-instead-of-maintaining-aspect-r) .

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](//stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers)

Answer (score 4):

This won't change the proportion of your video but gets rid of ugly 'unfilled' spaces at the top and bottom or sides of your video viewer IF your browser doesn't support the `object-fit:cover` style.

Let's say you have an in-page viewer that's 500x281 (a proper resizing from 1280x720). But sometimes you may get a video that's not properly proportioned to exactly 16:9, say 1278x720 or 320x176 as in the case of the 'Buck Bunny' video on the W3C site. It would be nice if the video filled the container completely and you don't have to create a new container for every improperly proportioned video.

Given a code fragment like:

```
<style>
#vidcontent {
  width:500;
  height:281;
  border:2px solid #F00;
  object-fit:cover; /* for those who do support it */
}
</style>

<video id="vidcontent" width="500" height="281" autoplay controls loop>
  <source src="http://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  Your browser does not support HTML5 video.
</video>
```

will render a video with black or white lines at the top and bottom depending on how your browser handles `object-fit`.  Add the following JavaScript for an on the fly height resizing of the video container making those lines go away by forcing your video container to match the video, at least vertically.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  vidContent = document.getElementById('vidcontent');
  vidContent.addEventListener("loadedmetadata", function(e) {
    var newHeight = (vidContent.width/this.videoWidth) * this.videoHeight;
    vidContent.style.height = parseInt(Math.ceil(newHeight)) + "px";
  }, false);
</script>
```

We divide the current width of the container by the determined width of the video stream then multiply by the determined height of the video stream.  That results in what the height of the container needs to be to force as clean of a fit as possible.

It is important that the video height and width are set as attributes in the HTML in addition to the CSS definition.

Answer (score 0):

The main thing is setting the object-fit property to fill for the video component, then you can choose any arbitrary values in the video-cover for the aspect ratio

```css
video {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: fill;
}

.video-cover {
  width: 50vw;
  height: 30vw;
  margin: 2rem;
  background: #2c3e50;
}
```

```html
<div class="video-cover">
  <video></video>
</div>
```