# Delete white spaces on html5 video tag in Ionic

Tags: css, angularjs, cordova, html5-video, ionic-framework

I have a `video` tag in my Ionic app, video element is added after click on a button.

```
function addVideo(videoId){
        var path = $scope.getVideo(videoId).newVideoLocation.nativeURL;
        path = $sce.trustAsResourceUrl(path);

        var container = document.getElementById('videoContainer' + videoId);
        var video =  document.createElement('video');

        video.src = path;
        video.setAttribute('id', 'video' + videoId);
        video.setAttribute('poster', $scope.getVideo(videoId).thumbnailPath);
        video.setAttribute('width', '100%');

        container.appendChild(video);
    };
```

Video is added successfully but there are bottom and top white spaces / bars:

[image]

After click play button spaces are no longer there:

[image]

I set border to all elements to know what is happening. Blue border is video tag:

[image]

It could be margin o padding however I set them to 0:

```
* {
    border: 1px solid red !important;
  }

  video {
    border: 2px solid blue !important;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
  }
```

Any idea what is the problem?

Comment: Have you tried to set `vertical-align:top`on `video`element

Comment: It might be size of poster, when you click poster is replaced with video

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of research I found a solution.

I start understanding what happened after read [HTML 5 Video stretch post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3779771/html-5-video-stretch):

> Video content should be rendered inside the element's playback area
>   such that the video content is shown centered in the playback area at
>   the largest possible size that fits completely within it, with the
>   video content's aspect ratio being preserved. Thus, if the aspect
>   ratio of the playback area does not match the aspect ratio of the
>   video, the video will be shown letterboxed or pillarboxed. Areas of
>   the element's playback area that do not contain the video represent
>   nothing.

Then in google books [I found and explanation how works video width](https://books.google.nl/books?id=er_CI68Vp7cC&lpg=PA15&ots=aX4cdgwBN3&dq=video%20poster%20size&hl=es&pg=PA15#v=onepage&q=video%20poster%20size&f=false), the book is call [The Definitive Guide to HTML5 Video](http://www.apress.com/9781430230908)

If width and height are not same aspect ratio as original video it doesn't work. Set a 100% to width doesn't mean you want video to fit the container. So I decided to calculate width and height of the container and set to `video` element:

```
function addVideo(videoId){
    var path = getTrustUrl($scope.getVideo(videoId).newVideoLocation.nativeURL);

    // Create container element and get padding 
    var container = document.getElementById('videoContainer' + videoId);
    var paddingLeft = window.getComputedStyle(container, null).getPropertyValue('padding-left');
    var paddingRight = window.getComputedStyle(container, null).getPropertyValue('padding-right');

    // Get only numeric part and parse to integer
    paddingLeft = parseInt(paddingLeft.slice(0,-2));
    paddingRight = parseInt(paddingRight.slice(0,-2));

    //Get internal width of container and calculate height
    var width = container.offsetWidth - paddingLeft - paddingRight;
    var height = (width * 9 ) / 16; // TODO, if not 16:9 error

    // Create video element and set attributes
    var video =  document.createElement('video');
    video.src = path;
    video.setAttribute('id', 'video' + videoId);
    video.setAttribute('poster', $scope.getVideo(videoId).thumbnailPath);
    video.setAttribute('width', width);
    video.setAttribute('height', height);

    // Append video to container
    container.appendChild(video);
};
```

I don't see it straightforward... if someone know another solution let me know!