# Make HTML background video height small and width 100%

Tags: html, css

I am trying to add a background video to a site and I am trying to make its height equal to 400px and and width equal to 100%. However, when I add 400px height, its width becomes small. I don't the video to go full screen , I want it to be just 400px of height (or a little bigger) and 100% of width just like at airbnb.com .

Here is HTML :

```
    <html>
    <head>

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <script src="bootstrap/js/jquery-3.1.0.min.js"></script>
        <script src="bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>

        <div id="videoDiv">
            <video autoplay loop mute id="video">
                <source src="video/video.mp4" type="video/mp4">
            </video> 
        </div>
        <div>
            <h1>Hello</h1>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

And here is CSS :

```
    #videoDiv{
    height: 400px!important;
}
#video{
    position: fixed;
    max-height: 400px!important;
    min-width: 100%;
}
```

[Here](http://softbroz.com/video%20test/) is the link of it. Kindly help!

Comment: have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/a/3780896/3755692

Comment: But when i add min-width: 100% and min-height: 100% it goes on full screen!

Comment: So it means that I have to change the aspect ratio of video manually to make it work?

Comment: probably because the video is 16:9 and your screen is 16:9 as well (or any other resolution which matches). if you try to have the video in for example 16:3, but the video is 16:9, then blank space is added left and right of the video

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default stylesheet for video elements is `object-fit: contain;` so it always keeps it's dimension ratio. So all you need to do is do "fill" instead to override that. Like this:

```
#video{
    position: fixed;
    max-height: 400px;
    min-width: 100%;
    object-fit: fill;
}
```

Comment: Also you probably won't need the `important` if you do it this way.