# How to lock a 3x3 grid to the viewport regardless of content size?

Tags: html, css, grid, viewport

I'm trying to create a page for CCTV camera streams that displays 9 streams in a 3x3 grid, using the full available width and height, without scrolling. The streams are different resolutions but I want the grid to resize the videos (ignoring aspect ratio, the video player handles this) so every video is visible.

I have this so far but I can't get the grid to resize the video elements so everything stays in the viewport.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

#container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  height: 100vh;
}

.item {
  border: 2px solid red;
  background-color: blue;
}

.item video {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div class="item">
    <video src="https://placehold.co/600x500.mp4" />
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <video src="https://placehold.co/600x400.mp4" />
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <video src="https://placehold.co/600x400.mp4" />
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <video src="https://placehold.co/600x400.mp4" />
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <video src="https://placehold.co/600x400.mp4" />
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <video src="https://placehold.co/600x400.mp4" />
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <video src="https://placehold.co/600x400.mp4" />
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <video src="https://placehold.co/600x400.mp4" />
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <video src="https://placehold.co/600x400.mp4" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This SO post has a solution. Maybe it still works. Uses object-fit css. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3779771/html-5-video-stretch

Comment: @GetSet I already tried this but this causes the videos to stretch to match the largest cell. I want all 9 cells to have the same width/height on the screen regardless of the video resolution.

Comment: What have you tried specifically and can you update your question to include your object-fit code attempt? In this way, the community can help with debugging that strategy as it applies to your use-case.

Comment: if you can ignore aspect-ratio why don't you use object-fit : fill;

Comment: Indeed, probably the closest you will get *sans* a Javascript solution to adjust sizing on the fly. https://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/XWQdMpm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To ensure the 9 cells take up exactly the viewport all elements have had box sizing defined, so borders are within their dimensions, all margins have been set to 0, and the videos are positioned absolute within their cells and given object-fit contain so it is certain the whole video will be seen without stretching.

If you want instead the videos to fill their cells then use cover instead, but of course they will probably get cropped.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(3, 1fr);
  height: 100vh;
}

.item {
  border: 2px solid red;
  background-color: blue;
  position: relative;
}

.item video {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: contain;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div class="item">
    <video src="https://placehold.co/600x500.mp4" />
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <video src="https://placehold.co/600x400.mp4" />
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <video src="https://placehold.co/600x400.mp4" />
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <video src="https://placehold.co/600x400.mp4" />
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <video src="https://placehold.co/600x400.mp4" />
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <video src="https://placehold.co/600x400.mp4" />
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <video src="https://placehold.co/600x400.mp4" />
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <video src="https://placehold.co/600x400.mp4" />
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <video src="https://placehold.co/600x400.mp4" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you! This works perfectly. I really need to learn how relative & absolute positioning works in css!

Answer (score 1):

ok then let me update it a little bit

```
body {
  margin: 0;
}

#container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(3, 1fr);
  height: 100vh;
}

.item {
  border: 2px solid #222;
  background-color:black;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.item video {
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 object-position: center;
}
```

**Here is the result (every video is responsive **

[image]

*

1. Added grid-template-rows: repeat(3, 1fr); to ensure the grid has 3 rows.
2. Added position: relative; and overflow: hidden; to the .item class to contain the video within the grid item.
3. The video has width and height of 100% that means it won't cut any angle *

- 

Comment: This hides the content unfortunately which is not what I want. I need the videos to be resized to fit the grid cells while keeping everything in the viewport. Thanks though.

Comment: I would recommend setting the width to 'auto', this would ensure that the aspect ratio is maintained.

Comment: Thanks, the updated version works great now! I have accepted the other answer just because it didn't have to alter the overflow but yours works just as well.